# bad request error 400 firebase but function works

Tags: node.js, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a function in my REST API that change a value in a document stored in firebase cloud firestore. I've wrote this function and tested with postman :

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/unsubNewsletter/:userId', newsletterStop);
```

user.js

```
exports.newsletterStop = (req,res) =>{
    const document = db.doc(`/users/${req.params.userId}`);
    document
        .get()
        .then(doc =>{
            if(!doc.exists){
                return res.status(404).json({error: 'User not found'})
            } else {
                document.update({newsletter:false})
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
};
```

The value changed in targeted document but postman shows me this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
```

What can I do to resolve this?

PS if construct that controls if a document exists doesn't check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions) `you should always end an HTTP function with send(), redirect(), or end(). Otherwise, your function might continue to run and be forcibly terminated by the system`.

Add something like:

```
document.update({newsletter:false})
.then(() => {
  res.status(200).send('Done!');
})
```